# How to put an input into an array and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([])


return (
  <input onChange={(event)=> setArray(event.target.value)} />

  <p>{array}</p>
);
```

Sorry, i have no code example that i can show you. however the question is understandable. I want an input from a user and store it into an array, after that, i display it. Can you please answer it in a ReactJs way.

I've tried putting state hooks, and i haven't figure it out, on how to display it. The thing i want is i want the input to be store in the variable as a string and display it. Somepeople told me that i should use the .map() method, but i do not know how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Why are you trying to store a single value in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this way,here it is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import uid to get unique id's 
import { v1 as uuid } from "uuid";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
// Hold array state(inputs)
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
       //Update the array on entering inputs
      <input onChange={(e) => setArray((pre) => [...pre, e.target.value])} />
      // Display Input values
      <div>
        {array.length > 0 && array.map((text) => <p key={uuid()}>{text} </p>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick way to get what you want.

You can also use **[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** which is recommended way to update the reference of Array.

In your case, setArray(event.target.value) won't help, because setArray() **expects a Array** but event.target.value is just an **string**.

So take a look at the below code snippet which takes a temporary array and adds it to your state variable. Because updating array means two things

1. Updating elements in array ( add, delete, modify elements )
2. Updating the reference of array.

Since you want to display the array on UI. It's **reference** **also** has to be updated along with value, so that react knows and React's DOM will be updated with new Array value and UI will be refreshed.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([])


pushIntoArray(value) {
    let tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(value);
    setArray(tempArray);
}

return (
  <input onChange={(event)=> pushIntoArray(event.target.value)} />

  <p>{array}</p>
);
```

So, tempArray helps to get new reference each time.

**You can also use **[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** which is recommended way to update the reference of Array.**

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I've added the explanation you suggested. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you pass into `setArray()` will become the new value of `array`. Currently your onChange function will not add the target value into the array, it will replace it entirely. To add the value ***into*** `array` you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new array which will include all the existing values, and the new value you want to add. Then pass that into the `setArray()`, instead of just the latest value from your input:
`<input onChange={(event) => setArray([...array, event.target.value])} />`

To display the values from your array you could use `.map()` to put each value in a paragraph element:
`{array.length ? array.map(value => <p>{value}</p>) : null}`

The above code uses a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236789/how-to-put-an-input-into-an-array-and-display-it) to check if there are any values in the array. If there are more than 0 elements in the array, the `array.map(...)` method returns a paragraph element for each element in the array. If there are no elements in the array the above line will return `null`, which will render nothing to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know ternanry operator. thanx 4 reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState([]);
  const [string, setString] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setString(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setArray((prevState) => [...prevState, string])}>
        Enter
      </button>
      <br />
      {array}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Am not sure this might be correct way to do it . Use One piece of state to store string and then push with a button atleast that how a real scenario would look like
Look at this PEN might help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hgqbmw?file=App.tsx

Comment: i appreciate your answer thank you